# Proving that if $A \subseteq B \cup C$, then $A \cap B \subseteq B \cap C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove the following?

> If $A \subseteq B \cup C$, then $A \cap B \subseteq B \cap C$.

I have the following:
Suppose that $A \subseteq B \cup C$ and let $x \in A \cap B$. Since $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Since $A \subseteq B \cup C$, then we have that $x \in B \cup C$. Therefore $x \in B$ or $x \in C$. -- I'm not sure where to go from here?

Comment: The statement does not seem to be true. If $A=B=\{0\}$, $C=\{1\}$ we have $A\subset B\cup C=\{0,1\}$, but $A\cap B = \{0\}$,  which is not contained in $B\cap C=\emptyset$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is false.
$A=\{1,2,3,4\}$

$B=\{1\}$

$C=\{2,3,4\}$

Then we have that $\{1,2,3,4\}=A$ $\subseteq B$ $\cup C=\{1,2,3,4\}$

but $A \cap B=\{1\} \not\subseteq B \cap C=\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

You know a point $a \in A$ is either in $B$ or $C$.

Now you are looking at a point $x$ which is in $A\cap B$.

You know that

1. it's in $A$, so either in $B$ or $C$
2. it's in $B$

so it must be in $B$ and/or $B\cap C$.

It's however not impossible that it is in $B$ but not in $C$, so the statement seems false.